# Getting error "Unable to Locate element"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using selenium webdriver 2.53 and firefox 43.0.1. I am exported the ide test case to TestNG and find the error "Unable to Locate element"

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  <span class="nav-label">My Profile</span>
  <span class="fa arrow"></span>
</a>
```

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"link text","selector":"My Profile"}

Comment: Try this xpath `//span[contains(text(), 'My Profile')]`

Comment: Try to wait until element become clickable with Explicit wait (http://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html#3) or check whether element located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Thank you Anderson and Jainish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath.

Using `text` method of `<span>` tag.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'My Profile')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`By.linkText` doesn't work on `<span>` tags, only `<a>` tags. Use `xpath` instead

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'My Profile')]")
```

Comment: Wrong! It should work for `span` that embedded in `a`

Comment: @Andersson From the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) `a By which locates A elements by the exact text it displays`. "My Profile" is not exact text of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: No. "My Profile" is exact visible link text which can be located `By.linkText`. `Span` is not actually separate web-element- it's just allow to apply `CSS` style to part of text content that differs from `CSS` style of the whole text content

Comment: @Andersson Clearly it's not working here. I've run into the same situation also where `LinkText()` doesn't work when other tags are contained in the `A`.

Comment: @Guy You should be able to remove the `contains()` since the exact text is "My Profile" in that `SPAN`. I like to be as specific as possible to avoid grabbing the wrong element now (or later).

Comment: @JeffC, ussually `linkText` **works fine** with `span` inside anchor... even with `div`. If you've faced some specific issue, please share details, I'll be happy to help you resolve it :)